# Modal UIViewController always coming out full screen on iPad. WHY?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple modal dialog on the iPad, in either the small (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) or the larger (UIModalPresentationPageSheet) settings, but they come out full screen (with a title bar) no matter what I do.

The modal UIViewController was created in interface builder where I can't seem to specify a size for it. Specifying a smaller size for the UIView contained within the UIViewController has no effect.

What am I doing wrong? What would possibly affect this issue? Could it be the timing in which I am setting modalPresentationStyle? I have tried both using a UINavigationController and without, but am getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured this out. Turns out I was using UIModalPresentationPageSheet, which always goes to full screen **in portrait mode**. Because my modal UIViewController wasn't responding to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, it was forcing a portrait orientation, which is why I THOUGHT the modal popup wasn't working.

By simply adding a shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation handler to my modal UIViewController, that returns YES, I now see that in landscape mode I **am** getting a large popup that covers most (but not all) of the screen, which is what I've been expecting.

Answer (score 5):

You must set `modalPresentationStyle` in the parent ViewController *before* calling `presentModalViewController:animated`.

```
myViewController = // create your new controller if needed 
myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
// "self" is the parent ViewController
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES]
```

Comment: Does this mean that the entire hierarchy is supposed to be modal? Because as I understand it, my root (top) UIViewController is a normal, non-modal view. Should I have shown that one with presentModalViewController:animated, too?

Comment: No, parent can be a non-modal UIViewController.