# what type of view controller is this?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

and how do you create it? - the popup one in the middle

[image: http://blogs.plos.org/mfenner/files/2011/01/IMG_0040-500x375.jpg]

I would lie to use something like this for my game (in the main menu).

Comment: It looks like a custom (Subclassed) UIViewController to me, displayed morally.

Comment: modally you mean? doesnt modal cover the screen entirely?

Comment: Not on an iPad.  You can set the display style to sheet.

Comment: oh ok how do you do that? and can you post it as an answer ill tick it if it works

Comment: Do you know how to create a new view controller?  Are you using storyboards, xibs, or doing it in code?

Comment: Well i with a xib i guess ill do it with. but initing it with code from another view controller of course. I havent exactly done this before though. I have done it with storyboard. Right now I'm just preparing a nib of the new view controller.

Comment: I'm headed to bed, but maybe this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672385/937822 will help you display it.  If you still don't have an answer, I'll post a more detailed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type for `UIViewController`. There are different ways how you can present `UIViewController`.

iPad support following three type:

1. Full Screen
2. Page Sheet
3. From Sheet

Your image is showing third one `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

You can Find detail of how to use this three type of presentation at following app guide:
[Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1).

Comment: This is pretty much the answer I was looking for although I already found it using the link inafziger gave me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

That's the link to the documentation.

[Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

A modal view controller is a controller that can be presented on top of another one.

To create it, for example, you can just call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method of the current view controller, passing in the view controller you want to present.

Since the interface you have uploaded contains a navigation bar that contains a close bar button item, you can simply wrap the controller you want to present in a navigation controller.

```
YourViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Otherwise, you can create a plain controller and use a `UIToolBar`.

Hope that helps.

P.S. The close button will not be there for free. You need to add it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much better to use a third party library instead of implementing it. There are many libraries that offer similar functionality.

- [UAModalPanel](https://github.com/coneybeare/UAModalPanel)

  [MTPopupWindow](https://github.com/icanzilb/MTPopupWindow)

  [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal)

If you do not want to use the above libraries, you can use UIModalPresentationFormSheet explained by Apple in this document: [Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you think an external library is better?

Comment: Usually i recommend not using third party libraries but in some cases you have to avoid reinventing the wheel and save yourself some time.